# Change bar or Revision bar count from PDF using Java

Tags: java

We are looking solution in Java to read how many revision bar present in PDF with revised text in summary report.
[PDF data is attached as image where it contains 2 revision bar with revised data in yellow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULVH1.jpg)